# Alternatives for select element in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to create inline lable with select element using bootstrap,

http://jsfiddle.net/kokilajs/1q53pr6j/

```
<form id="searchForm"  method="get" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="GPA" class="col-xs-2 control-label">GPA :</label>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input name="GPA" type="number" value="2.5" class="form-control"                 id="GPA"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <label for="faculty" class="control-label">Faculty:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="faculty">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And I failed ! :(  then I searched and found **[this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#textual-%3Cinput%3Es-only)**

> Avoid using `<select>` elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers.

what is the alternative for this ? they don't mentioned there.. Is there good method to do that without lot of hacks ?

### update : Avoid using `<select>` elements

in bootstrap page they **[noted](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#textual-%3Cinput%3Es-only)** , I need to know is there cross browser compatibility issue or something ? with select element ? if it is what are the alternatives for select element ?

Comment: yeh thnkz it is ok, another thing is I need clarification about Avoid using <select> elements ? then what can I use ?

Comment: what does it mean, select alternatives in the sense you need custom select box?

Comment: they mentioned [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#textual-%3Cinput%3Es-only) Avoid using <select> elements here as they cannot be fully styled in WebKit browsers. I have doubt is this select element responsiveness or styli is failed on another browser,I mean cross browser compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you are referring is only for using `Input groups` not for inline form.. So you can use like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1q53pr6j/2/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="col-xs-4">  <label for="faculty" class="control-label">Faculty:</label></div>
         <div class="col-xs-8">
        <select class="form-control" name="faculty">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
             </select></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To know more about inline form refer this **[Link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use inline-form structure from bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Remove all classes like "col-xs" and wrap label/field in `<div class="form-group">`
And you must specify width for your input and select fields.

```
input, select {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

> **May require custom widths**
>   Inputs and selects have width: 100%; applied
>   by default in Bootstrap. Within inline forms, we reset that to width:
>   auto; so multiple controls can reside on the same line. Depending on
>   your layout, additional custom widths may be required.

You can see demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/1q53pr6j/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

## [DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/1q53pr6j/7/)   // your required mobile view

## [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/1q53pr6j/8/)   // Actual mobile view

Hope this will be useful for you..

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <label for="GPA" class="control-label">GPA :</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <input name="GPA" type="number" value="2.5" class="form-control" id="GPA" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <label for="faculty" class="control-label">Faculty:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <select class="form-control" name="faculty">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `form-inline` class on your form tag :

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="searchForm"  method="get" class="form-inline" role="form">
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="GPA" class="control-label">GPA :</label>
     <input name="GPA" type="number" value="2.5" class="form-control"                    id="GPA"/>
 </div> 
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="faculty" class="control-label">Faculty:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="faculty">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
        </select>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline textbox using bootstrap
Like this way you want

```
<form id="searchForm"  method="get" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">GPA</span>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
    </div>

</form>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1q53pr6j/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS for the select element.

```
.selectClassName {
    max-width: 90%;
    display: inline;
}
```